# Limit download speed if filesize 20mb

Tags: networking, proxy, downloads, bandwidth

Is there a software like trickle lets say for example?

That i can put as a proxy and lets say set it up so that if a filesize that i am downloading is over 20MB it will limit it to 2kb?

I found trickle but it doesnt seem to be that configurable.

Comment: `I found trickle but it doesnt seem to be that configurable.` What configurable exactly?